# Retrieve mssql primary key from query?

Tags: sql-server, get, primary-key

In C# Visual Studio Express Windows Forms:
How do I retrieve the primary key of a just executed insert query.

Here is my con+query code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...);
SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();    
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bestillinger (ha) VALUES (@ha);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ha", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());            
con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

With a manual `Close()`, you risk leaking a connection if the code that uses it throws an exception.  So please use `using` instead.

Assuming your PK is an `identity` column, the new value is most easily retrieved with [`scope_identity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    con.Open();
    var command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = @"
         INSERT INTO bestillinger (ha) VALUES (@ha);
         select scope_identity();";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ha", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    var newPk = (long) command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Andomar said in his answer, ensure you properly close the connection.

Another way to return the value of the newly inserted identity field would be:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    con.Open();
    var command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = @"
         INSERT INTO bestillinger (ha) OUTPUT inserted.[ID] VALUES (@ha);";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ha", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    var newPk = (long) command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

`[ID]` would be replaced with the name of the identity field (or any field, or fields) that you want.